# What does "pneumatic" mean when applied to a person?

Tags: adjectives, meaning-in-context

For example, in [this review of the movie Unknown](http://www.guardian.co.uk/film/2011/jul/17/giallo-unknown-country-kermode-dvd), Mark Kermode refers to Liam Neeson's character's wife as being played by "*X-Men's* **pneumatic** January Jones".

I'm never quite sure whether this refers to her attitude, her physique, a particular aspect of her physique, or something else. I don't think I've ever seen the word used to describe a man. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read Aldous Huxley's *Brave New World* for more on this.

Comment: Literally it means inflated with air.  You can guess which part of her anatomy appears to be inflated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When a female is described as **pneumatic** it means she has *large breasts* (possibly artificially augmented by plastic surgery).

To my mind, there's also the implication of her being both well-equipped and possibly available for [bouncy bouncy](http://www.slang-dictionary.com/definition/bouncy-bouncy.html) / [mattress dancing](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/mattress-dance) (slang euphemisms for sexual intercourse).

Per @z7sg's answer and @Jimi Oke's comment, Aldous Huxley particularly favoured the word, using it no less than **15 times** in Brave New World! (less than half have any sexual connotation though - the majority are *pneumatic chairs/sofas/shoes/etc.*) Huxley's usage, which strikes me as somewhat bizarre, seems only loosely related to the standard meaning today.

The modern (sexist, to my ear) usage may have started with T.S. Eliot's [Uncorseted, her friendly bust / Gives promise of pneumatic bliss](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/uncorseted-her_friendly_bust-gives_promise_of/263940.html) (*Whispers of Immortality*, 1920). 
Over a hundred years earlier, and still sometimes today, the *pneumatic body* has been used to mean *spiritual body* which would be resurrected (as opposed to *corporeal body* which decays after death - see [1 Cor. 15:44](http://www.directionjournal.org/article/?1527)).

I've never heard the term applied to a man, but if I *did* come across it, I wouldn't infer any sexual or spiritual conotations - I'd just assume it meant someone who looked a bit like the [Michelin Man](http://www.brandchannel.com/features_profile.asp?pr_id=212).

Comment: +1 for conflating (OK, juxtposing — couldn't resist) Eliot's high-toned drollery with everyday strip-club speech.

Comment: ... *juxtaposing* ... Stupid fingers on stupid keyboard typing stupid letters.

Comment: Ah, but even spelt correctly,  *juxtaposing* usually implies only **two** correlated concepts. I had the high and low-toned sexual references *plus* the ineffably more spiritual *spiritual* connotation from St Paul!

Comment: Yes, but I only referenced two of your references. In any set of *n* members where *n* > 2, two may be in a juxtapositional relationship with each other at any given time, irrespective of any relationships with other set members.

Comment: I've also seen the word used in a context where it appeared to be applied to the person's manner of speech -- verbose and loud with more air than content.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I'm not consciously aware of having heard that usage, but I suppose it's an allusion to someone sounding like a ***pneumatic hammer*** (very loud and *very **very*** annoying). I kinda doubt the *[hot] air* connotations would be much in the mind of anyone using it.

Comment: Perhaps the equivalent term for a man would be *hydraulic*.

Answer (score 17):

There is a precedent for the usage of the word *pneumatic* to describe the desirable female character Lenina Crowne in Aldous Huxley's *Brave New World*.

> "Lenina Crowne?" said Henry Foster, echoing the Assistant Predestinator's question as he zipped up his trousers. "Oh, she's a splendid girl. Wonderfully pneumatic. I'm surprised you haven't had her."

In describing Lenina, *pneumatic* means well-rounded, curvy, and bouncy, in the sexual sense of the word.

> "Every one says I'm awfully pneumatic," said Lenina reflectively, patting her own legs.

Before this it was used by T.S. Eliot in the poem [*Whispers of Immortality*](http://www.infoplease.com/t/lit/poems-eliot-ts/10.html), conveying the sensual pleasure of a woman's bosom.

> Grishkin is nice: her
>   Russian eye is underlined for emphasis;
>   Uncorseted, her friendly bust
>   Gives promise of pneumatic bliss.

Comment: *Brave New World* is **exactly** what I thought of when I read the question title; Huxley seems to love the word.

Comment: @Reid Yes he does, and his frequent use of the word has often been remarked upon by BNW-ophiles http://bravenewworldpr.blogspot.com/2011/02/pneumatic.html

Comment: I also remember reading this in *Brave New World* specifically.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I'm not surprised you remember! He used the word **fifteen times** in one book!

Comment: I believe Huxley consciously invented it as a piece of slang for his sci-fi world; as Burgess did in A Clockwork Orange, but on a smaller scale. It's for the reader to interpret, but I never saw it as curvy/bouncy, but more lithe and well muscled, the better to make repetitive vigorous mechanical movements, like a pneumatic drill.

Answer (score 6):

Without looking at an image of the woman, and without knowing the X-Men reference, I would say the lady is *full-breasted*.

The implication is that the figure has an *inflated* appearance -- hence the word 'pneumatic'.

I have seen the word used that way before ... but I'm not sure it has been used to describe a man.

Comment: Perhaps I was being a little coy, and I should have said *full-breasted* [edited now]. Who knows what Hollywood make-up artists could do with an *X-Men* character. Besides, Mark Kermode might think so.

Answer (score 1):

I always interpreted Lenina's line in a more explicitly sexual way, given the context.  My first thought was pneumatic tube systems and the suction involved in making them work. "Pneumatic" refers to pressurized gas systems.  I did just look it up just now though and found another usage I was unaware of, "of or relating to the spirit".  Maybe that's what she meant.  They did have a lot of sex in that utopian world!

Answer (score -1):

containing or operated by air or gas under pressure